# WinMerge のディレクトリ diff 相当のシェルコマンドはあるか

Tags: shellscript, unix

WinMerge というツールがあります。

これは Windows 上のツールで様々な diff をとるためのツールですが、その機能の中に次のようなものがあります。

- ディレクトリ構造 (のようなもの) を２つ引数にとり比較する。
- ディレクトリ構造には、ディレクトリ自身や、 zip などの圧縮ファイルを任意に指定可能 (拡張子で自動判定して、必要に応じて展開してから比較をしてくれる）

これと同等の機能を持った CUI 上のツールはありますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
$ diff -qr dir1 dir2
```

zip は知らない